# How to change text value of several pages at the same time

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am using GetX to develop an App. I have several pages that should show the same text value(Every page has its own text widget, and these text widgets should show the same value). When I click a button in Setting Page. These pages should change the text value at the same time?
How to accomplish global notification in GetX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare the value you want to show across your app to be observable so the controller can keep track of it

```
String sameValue = "same value".obs;
```

and the way you want show it on the UI is like

```
Obx(() => Text("${your_controller.sameValue}"))
```

Comment: are 'sameValue' and 'your_controller' global variables? Because Several pages need to update.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I assumed you already declared your controller and values.
In a nutshell, you have to create a business logic class that extends GetXController, declare sameValue in it, and your home UI class can extend this business logic class and you can declare your controller and get it's observables.
Please check out the "Counter app with GetX" part of the package description on pub, I think it will help you a lot
https://pub.dev/packages/get#counter-app-with-getx